# Responsive selectbox

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, unsemantic-css

I'm using [unsemantic.css](https://unsemantic.com), have a basic layout:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-65">
    Some content here
  </div>

  <div class="grid-35">
    <select>
      <option value="0">First option</option>
      <option value="1">Second</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like **select box** to have a width equal to it's parent div (35% of a grid row). Default width of this element is determined by lenght of it's options.

Tried:

```
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But that had no effect over all.
When I set width to some specific value (500 px), it works well but is not responsive.

Comment: Does select have some other styles except `width: 100%`? I tried to inset select on demopage — all works fine https://i.imgur.com/3g934BS.png

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle?

Comment: edit: I've tried width: auto; setting it to 100% works fine.This should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Matěj Štágl the problem is that the select is an inline-block by default.
Simply make it a block element and make its width 100%, and it will be responsive.
The following code will help you out.

```
    select{
     display : block;
     width : 100%
    }
```